# Error page in MVC while error occurred from Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application I am using custom error attribute class inherited from HandleErrorAttribute to globally handle the exceptions.

My objective is :

1. Showing error page while exception occurred.
2. Showing a custom error page.

In my application most of the control action method are called using Ajax.I am able to show the error page when exception occurs for those controller action where Ajax call is not used but in the case of Ajax call error is logged but error page is not displaying.

Comment: You have to capture the Ajax error separately by setting up the error trap in ajax configuration.

Comment: can you please explain with a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the error trap in ajax setup:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            alert('Time out error.');
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
        } else {
            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

Obviously, you can do anything when the error is caught.